# Allow chained method calls in certain orders only

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-chaining

I have a Python3 class that supports method chaining.

For example, I have methods `a()`, `b()` and `c()`. How can I allow `c()` to only be chained after `a()` or in another thought, how can I allow `b()` not to be chained next with function `c()`?

```
✘ a().b().c()
✘ b().c()
✓ a().c() #only allow this sequence
```

Is this possible?

Edit:

To define method chaining is self-explanatory in programming. It is basically calling methods in a chain.

> method_a().method_b().method_c()

#### Class Structure

```
class Test:
   def a(self):
      ...
      return self

   def b(self):
      ...
      return self

   def c(self):
      ...
      return self
```

Comment: It's possible, but seems like extremely bad practice.

Comment: Please post a [mre] with expected behavior

Comment: "Method chaining" means `a().b().c()`? Then either keep some internal state in the object and let each method throw an exception if the object is not in the correct state, or return an object from the respective methods which only has or hasn't certain methods.

Comment: @deceze updated the question for more details. I hope that is enough to open it back.

Comment: This very much depends on how your method chaining is implemented in the first place. Do methods return self or a proxy? What do you even mean by "allow b() not to be chained next with function c()" – should an error be thrown, or should some static checker emit a warning, or something else? Why is it even possible to chain them at the moment if this is not valid as well?

Comment: When you say "I have a Python3 class that supports method chaining", do you just mean that you have a bunch of methods that return `self`?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi updated the question to contain the class structure. To answer your question, yes an error should be thrown  in cases where a method should not follow a particular method when chained.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Updated the question to contain the class structure. To answer, yes supposedly.

Comment: So, start each method with `if self.shouldnt_be_called_right_now: raise Exception`? Fill in your business logic for the condition.

Comment: I don't see how returning ``self`` lends itself to specific method orders. *All* methods of an object should be valid at any time; that's the point of classes/types. Either ``.b()`` is valid on *all* or on *no* instances of ``Test``. Sure, it's technically possible to break a type to conform to such a scheme but it will be inherently flawed. Do you actually need to the return value to be ``self``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In python, the only way to allow method chaining is to return self. To give more context. I have this line for example: `query.WHERE('column_name').EQ('value')`. I only want to allow `EQ()` to only follow `WHERE()` and not the other way around.

Comment: @JorossBarredo well, no, your object just has to return *something* with the methods you describe. So, `query` object can return a `Where` object when `query.WHERE` is called, and the `Where.EQ` object can return something appropriate

Comment: @JorossBarredo As far as I can tell, ``query.WHERE('column_name')`` is not itself a query. You should consider having helpers for partial queries. Not only do you have to forbid the *action* of chaining ``query.EQ(...)``, but also the *neglect* of chaining ``.EQ(...)`` to ``query.WHERE(...)``. If ``query.WHERE('column_name')`` is just another query, there is nothing in the type system hinting that this is invalid.